# How to add filters in Existing video?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, avfoundation, ios8.3

I want to add filter effects in my existing captured video, I have tried to do this with  `GPUImageMovie(<GPUImage/GPUImage.h>)` but getting crash on     `[movieWriter startRecording];` so can you please suggest me if there is an any other proper way to do this.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just pass your existing videoURL it will be filtered, Don't forget to add GPUImage Framework.

```
- (void)testFilterOptions:(NSURL*)videoUrl{

    movieFile = [[GPUImageMovie alloc] initWithURL:videoUrl];
    movieFile.runBenchmark = YES;
    movieFile.playAtActualSpeed = NO;
    //filter = [[GPUImagePixellateFilter alloc] init];
    filter = [[GPUImageSepiaFilter alloc] init];

    [movieFile addTarget:filter];

    // Only rotate the video for display, leave orientation the same for recording
//    GPUImageView *filterView = (GPUImageView *)self.previewView;
//    [filter addTarget:filterView];

    // In addition to displaying to the screen, write out a processed version of the movie to disk
    NSString *pathToMovie = [NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Documents/Movie.mov"];
    unlink([pathToMovie UTF8String]); // If a file already exists, AVAssetWriter won't let you record new frames, so delete the old movie
    NSURL *movieURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:pathToMovie];

    movieWriter = [[GPUImageMovieWriter alloc] initWithMovieURL:movieURL size:CGSizeMake(480.0, 480.0)];
    [filter addTarget:movieWriter];

    // Configure this for video from the movie file, where we want to preserve all video frames and audio samples
    movieWriter.shouldPassthroughAudio = NO;
    movieFile.audioEncodingTarget = nil;
    [movieFile enableSynchronizedEncodingUsingMovieWriter:movieWriter];

    [movieWriter startRecording];
    [movieFile startProcessing];

    [movieWriter setCompletionBlock:^{
        [filter removeTarget:movieWriter];
        [movieWriter finishRecording];

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
      //Recording complete do whatever you want
        });
    }];
}
```